# javascript code not working when using in external file but working well in head tag and same code is working in other html file

Tags: javascript

Here is the javascript code my problem is that same javascript code is working in index file for same html code but not working in portfolio file and I have tried everything I can think of. I have used document dot ready function and adding script file in bottom of the body, and the code is working when I try it in console log

```js
$(function() {
        var selectedClass = "";
        $(".portfolio_btn").click(function(){ 
        selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel"); 
     $("#portfolio").fadeTo(100, 0.1);
        $(".portfolio_item").not("."+selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('scale-anm');

    setTimeout(function() {
      $("."+selectedClass).fadeIn().addClass('scale-anm');
      $("#portfolio").fadeTo(300, 1);
      $(".port")
    }, 300); 
        
    });
});

var header = document.getElementById("portfolio_btn_container");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("portfolio_btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("portfolio_btn active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.portfolio_container{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin-top:50px;
}
.portfolio_btn_container{
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 26%;
}
.portfolio_btn {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: normal;
    padding:8px 35px 10px 30px;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #1ABC9C;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    color: #555;
    outline:none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.portfolio_btn.active{
    background-color:#1ABC9C;
    color:white;
}

.portfolio{
    
    width:90%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left:5%;
    
}
.portfolio_item{
    webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease;
    transition: all 350ms ease;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.portfolio_item img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.portfolio_bio_inner{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
}
.portfolio_bio_text{
    font-size:25px;
    webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease;
    transition: all 350ms ease;
    color:#434343;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.portfolio_bio_h4{
    padding-left:75px;
}
.portfolio_bio_p{
    font-size:20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 25px;
}

.scale-anm {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.portfolio_item:hover .portfolio_bio_inner h4,.portfolio_item:hover .portfolio_bio_inner p{
    transform: scale(1);
}

.portfolio_item:hover .portfolio_bio_inner{
    background:white;
    opacity:0.8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfolio_container"><!--portfolio starts-->
 <div class="portfolio_title">
 <h2>Portfolio</h2>
  <p>web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text</p></div>
<div class="portfolio_btn_container" id="portfolio_btn_container">
  <button class="portfolio_btn active" href="" data-rel="all">All</button>
  <button class="portfolio_btn" data-rel="photo">Photo</button>
  <button class="portfolio_btn" data-rel="branding">Branding</button>
  <button class="portfolio_btn" data-rel="techno">Technology</button>
  <button class="portfolio_btn" data-rel="creative">Creative</button>
</div> 
   <div class="portfolio" id="portfolio"> 
        <div class="portfolio_item scale-anm branding all">
          <div class="portfolio_bio_inner">
          <h4 class="portfolio_bio_text portfolio_bio_h4">Business Plan</h4>
          <p class="portfolio_bio_text portfolio_bio_p">Randomised words which don look even slightly believable. If going to use a passage of Lorem</p>
          </div>
        <img src="assets/15-dia_1092-1-300x300.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        
        <div class="portfolio_item scale-anm photo all">
        <div class="portfolio_bio_inner">
          <h4 class="portfolio_bio_text portfolio_bio_h4">Business Plan</h4>
          <p class="portfolio_bio_text portfolio_bio_p">Randomised words which don look even slightly believable. If going to use a passage of Lorem</p>
          </div>
        <img src="assets/3387c282bae062cc6efada9402ef42ad.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        
         <div class="portfolio_item scale-anm techno all">
         <div class="portfolio_bio_inner">
          <h4 class="portfolio_bio_text portfolio_bio_h4">Business Plan</h4>
          <p class="portfolio_bio_text portfolio_bio_p">Randomised words which don look even slightly believable. If going to use a passage of Lorem</p>
          </div>
        <img src="assets/emi_haze-300x201.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        
         <div class="portfolio_item scale-anm creative all">
         <div class="portfolio_bio_inner">
          <h4 class="portfolio_bio_text portfolio_bio_h4">Business Plan</h4>
          <p class="portfolio_bio_text portfolio_bio_p">Randomised words which don look even slightly believable. If going to use a passage of Lorem</p>
          </div>
        <img src="assets/3387c282bae062cc6efada9402ef42ad.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        
         <div class="portfolio_item scale-anm photo all">
         <div class="portfolio_bio_inner">
          <h4 class="portfolio_bio_text portfolio_bio_h4">Business Plan</h4>
          <p class="portfolio_bio_text portfolio_bio_p">Randomised words which don look even slightly believable. If going to use a passage of Lorem</p>
          </div>
        <img src="assets/3387c282bae062cc6efada9402ef42ad.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        
         <div class="portfolio_item scale-anm branding all">
         <div class="portfolio_bio_inner">
          <h4 class="portfolio_bio_text portfolio_bio_h4">Business Plan</h4>
          <p class="portfolio_bio_text portfolio_bio_p">Randomised words which don look even slightly believable. If going to use a passage of Lorem</p>
          </div>
        <img src="assets/iPhone-Text-Monitoring-on-Apple-Devices-Yes-And-So-Much-More.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        
         <div class="portfolio_item scale-anm techno all">
         <div class="portfolio_bio_inner">
          <h4 class="portfolio_bio_text portfolio_bio_h4">Business Plan</h4>
          <p class="portfolio_bio_text portfolio_bio_p">Randomised words which don look even slightly believable. If going to use a passage of Lorem</p>
          </div>
        <img src="assets/pexels-photo-168765.jpeg" alt="" />
        </div>
        
         <div class="portfolio_item scale-anm creative all">
         <div class="portfolio_bio_inner">
          <h4 class="portfolio_bio_text portfolio_bio_h4">Business Plan</h4>
          <p class="portfolio_bio_text portfolio_bio_p">Randomised words which don look even slightly believable. If going to use a passage of Lorem</p>
          </div>
        <img src="assets/porfolio-4.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
      
        
         
   </div>
</div><!--portfolio ends-->
```

Comment: did you checked in developers tool whether the js file is loading or not?

Comment: i checked source file it is loading but not working other javascript code is working well

Comment: If it works in 1 html file but not in a different one, chances are the path is wrong. Can you add the part where the JS code is referenced in the 2 files? Is "the portfolio file" in a separate/sub directory or is it at the same root level as index.html?

Comment: it is a seperate directory

Comment: path is right because i have some other javascript code too that is working

Comment: Is JQuery only included in index but not in portfolio?

Comment: it is included in portfolio as well

Comment: Need more information, like directory structure (if using relative path) and the references to your js file

Comment: <script src="script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" ></script>
<script src="script/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: is the js file path and file Name correct?